# DataAnnotations in ViewModel w/o overriding DomainModel Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, data-annotations, domain-model

How to add `DataAnnotation` in View Model which inherits Domain Model without overriding its properties?

`User` Domain Model

```
public class User{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

`Register` View Model

```
public class Register : User{

  [Required]  
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Here, Is there a way to add `DataAnnotation` to `UserName` and `Password` with out inhering those properties in `Register` View model?

Comment: i dont think so it is possible without inheriting them

Comment: Why don't you put DataAnnotation on User class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a customrequired attribute and set its inherited property to false

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field 
    | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    { 
    }
```

So your User Domain model will be as below:

```
  public class User{

  [CustomRequired]
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  [CustomRequired]
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and now your Register Model will be as below

```
public class Register : User
{
public string Password{get;set;}
}
```

So now the required property will not be inherited by child class and if you dig down the `Required` Attribute you can find a definition for your `Inherited` boolean property which says as follows:

> Summary:
>            Gets or sets a Boolean value indicating whether the indicated attribute can be inherited by derived classes and overriding members.
>
> Returns:
>            true if the attribute can be inherited by derived classes and overriding members; otherwise, false. The default is true.